# How to install docker using puppet bolt task on windows machne

Tags: powershell, docker, puppet, puppet-bolt

I want to install `docker` on windows machine using `bolt task` command.

Is there any command similar to below for installing `docker` on windows machine.

```
bolt task run package action=install name=docker
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: You would need chocolatey for something like that command.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `bolt task run package action=install name=docker --targets <TARGET>`

As a commentor suggested, you'll need a package manager (Chocolatey) installed on your Windows machine for the package task to interact with. Check out [this doc](https://puppet.com/docs/bolt/latest/bolt_examples.html#deploy-a-package-with-bolt-and-chocolatey) - it gives instructions on writing a plan that installs Chocolatey and then uses the package task to install a package.